# Vizta V24Lmha1 high pitched whining on Windows, none on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

So I've got this Vizta monitor that I'm using for a secondary vertical monitor. Running off a EVGA GTX 970. When I'm in Windows 10, have it set for 1080p60hz, and it's whining like a madman. I've tried tweaking brightness on the monitor itself, via Nvidia control panel, etc. Still is whining rather hard. Nvidia Game Ready drivers are up to date.

Meanwhile, on Ubuntu, have 1080p60hz and there's no noise at all, using Nvidia 384.90. Is there something with Windows display drivers that could cause it to whine so much? Are there other things to try other than dropping refresh rate / brightness on the monitor? Could this be a manufacturing issue / bad monitor issue? Appreciate any thoughts or advice.

Comment: How's it connected? If the monitor has built in speakers, does muting them help?

Comment: Connected via HDMI - swapped out multiple cables, still get the same thing. There are built in speakers, tried muting them, bringing them to max - same deal. :(

Comment: OK, so the problem is only with audio. Are we correct in **assuming you also tested HDMI audio in Linux without issues**? Because if you didn't, mentioning Linux here is utterly irrelevant.

Comment: Not using the monitors for audio, my apologies if I insinuated I was using them. Some other topics had shown that was a potential fix so that's why I had included that.